# Is it proper to use a singleton for access to a "constant global array"?

Tags: java, arrays, singleton, global

I have an array of int which doesn't need to be modified.
The array is not available until the code is run as it uses some data from a file which it then modifies to generate the array values.

This array needs to be accessed from many classes. To my knowledge a poor way of doing this would be to constantly pass the array to functions, another worse way would be to declare as a global variable.

I have the intuition that maybe I should use a singleton, it would only hold an array of int and return an instance of that array when called. Assuming this is correct, what is the proper way to firstly pass that array to the singleton once and have it be set. Then what is the proper way to call the singleton and have an instance of the array returned?

Thanks

Comment: How do you view a singleton as different to a global variable (which you don't like)?

Comment: An array cannot be constant in java. Nothing stops anything accessing it modifying its contents.

Comment: I'm operating under the assumption that the need for a global variable is a design flaw and since this is probably a common case there must be a better way of doing it. 
I was thinking there is a design pattern or proper way to do something like this, I am however not sure if a singleton is the right solution either. In short I'll be honest, I'm not sure if a global variable or singleton is more incorrect.

@Andy in that case would I return a deep copy of the array instead?

Comment: Does it have to be an array? You could use `public static final List<Integer> LIST;`, then in a static initializer of the class you could add the elements to an `ArrayList<Integer>` called `temp` and write `LIST = Collections.unmodifiableList(temp)`.

Comment: removing all my assumptions the question I really have is :
"given an array of int that needs to be used by many different classes, what is the best way to give other classes access to this array? I would like to avoid passing the array each time a function requires it. Is there an alternative?"

Comment: @pbabcdef
The data currently is a 2D array and it is used as such by the other methods. I think my code would be less readable if it wasn't an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue here doesn't have to do with whether the array is global or not. You're pretty much doing the same thing with a singleton. Issues with global variables have to do with *shared state*, since *anyone* can access them and mess with them. Hence, it becomes very hard to reason about the state of such a variable or its life-cycle.

I would suggest wrapping the array inside a class of its own. This is, in effect, your singleton. The array would be a static member. Furthermore, instead of returning a reference to the array itself, return a **copy** of the array instead. This way no one can modify the array directly.

Your class could look like this:

```
//pick a better name; this is just for demo purposes
public class Singleton {
    private static int[] array = {};
    private static boolean initialized = false;

    public static void initialize(int[] arr) {
        if(!initialized) {
            array = new int[arr.length];
            System.arraycopy(arr, 0, array, 0, arr.length);
            initialized = true;
        } else {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Array has already been initialized");
        }
    }

    public static int[] getArray() {
        return Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length);  
    }
}
```

To be honest, this does seem a little inelegant and bulky with me. <s>Instead, perhaps you can try using an unmodifiable list ([`Collections.unmodifiableList(List<? extends T> list)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList(java.util.List))).</s> You mentioned that this was a 2D array, but you can still do this with unmodifiable lists; you'd just end up with `List<List<Integer>>`. Build up the inner lists first (values for a row), and then insert them into the outer list as unmodifiable lists. Then make the outer list itself an unmodifiable list. You can wrap this list inside an object of its own type, which would be a singleton (kind of like the array example above). Then, instead of giving access to a 2D array or the list itself, provide a `get(row, column)` method that retrieves an element from the lists. However, if you're doing this then you're probably fine leaving the the list as a regular list since there is no way anyone can modify it once initialized.

Comment: The code you provided seems to be what I had in mind when I was (maybe mistakenly) referring to a singleton. What is the added benefit of changing the object to an unmodified list? If I return a copy using copyOf as you specified above, is then using an unmodified list overkill since (in the code above) the array can't be directly modified?

Comment: @kyleLam If you use an unmodifiable list of unmodifiable lists (my preferred solution to this) then you don't have to return a copy because it can't be changed anyway. If you return an `int[][]` it probably should be a fresh copy each time because arrays are mutable.

Comment: @kyleLam Whether you use a list or an array, the idea is that you want to abstract access behind a specific class.  Instead of returning `int[][]`, you provide methods like `get(row, column)`. This way you don't let the implementation "leak" out. As far as the unmodifiable list question, I now realize it doesn't really matter if you are only providing access to the data through a method like `get(row, column)`; you can leave it as a regular list. The unmodifiable list comes into play only if you plan on returning the internal structure, which I don't think is a good idea anyway.